# Prove that $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} x(t)$ exists and is an integer.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, proof-writing

> Let $f : \Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ be a $\operatorname {C}^{\infty}$-function such that $f(x) = 0$ if and only if $x \in \Bbb Z.$ Suppose the function $x : \Bbb R \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ satisfies $x'(t) = f(x(t)),$ for all $t \in \Bbb R.$ If $\Bbb Z \cap \{x(t)\ |\ t \in \Bbb R \} = \varnothing,$ then show that $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty}  x(t)$ exists and is an integer.

What I have seen is that $x$ is also a $\operatorname {C}^{\infty}$- function and since image of $x$ doesn't contain any integer so by IVP it follows that $$\{x(t)\ |\ t \in \Bbb R \} \subseteq (a,b)$$ where $a, b \in \Bbb R$ with $b-a \leq 1$ such that $(a, b) \cap \Bbb Z = \varnothing.$ In other words the image of $x$ is strictly lying between two consecutive integers. Hence $x$ is bounded and also by the definition of $x'$ and $f$ it follows that $x'(t) \neq 0,$ for all $t \in \Bbb R.$

Now how do I proceed? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From $x'(t) \ne 0$ and $x'$ being continuous, we see that $x(t)$ must be monotone.

Comment: Why is it so @player3236? Can you please explain a bit more about it? Thanks.

Comment: If there are points $t_1$ and $t_2$ for which $x'(t_1) < 0 < x'(t_2)$, apply Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Oh! I see. Nice remark @player3236. Thanks. Then $x$ is monotone and bounded so the limit exists. Am I right? But why does it have to be an integer?

Comment: Yes. But I concede I have no idea why it must be an integer.

Comment: @player3236 I think continuity of $x'$ is not needed. Here IVP of $x'$ follows by Darboux's theorem.

Comment: @Phibetakappa yes, but continuity of $x'$ is implied by the ODE anyway

Comment: Thanks @Calvin Khor for a wonderful intuition. I have worked on it on my own and found the same conclusion what you argued in your answer. What I show is that if $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} x(t) = l$ and if $x'(t) > 0,\ $ for all $t \in \Bbb R$ then either $f(l) = 0$ or $f(l) > 0.$ Here what I note is that $l$ being the supremum of $x$ on $\Bbb R$ there will always exist some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $l - \varepsilon > \inf\limits_{t \in \Bbb R} x(t)$ (Because in that case $x$ is not a constant for otherwise $\{x(t)\ |\ t \in \Bbb R \} \cap \Bbb Z \neq \varnothing$).

Comment: Similar things will happen if $x$ was decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted $f$ has a sign in the domain of interest  let's say $f$ is positive here (using the $a$ from the OP, we are saying without loss of generality that $f$ is positive on $(\lfloor a \rfloor, \lfloor a \rfloor,+1)$), then $x$ is increasing and therefore (by the assumed boundedness of $x$) $l=\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)$ exists as a real number (*).

Suppose $l\not\in \mathbb Z$. Thus $f(l)\neq 0$. There is some $\epsilon$ such that if $x\in\mathbb R$ is such that $l\ge x>l-\epsilon$, then $|f(x)-f(l)|<f(l)/2$, and hence $|f(x)|=f(x) \ge f(l)/2$.

For all sufficiently large times, we have $l\ge x(t) > l - \epsilon_1 $, and therefore  $$x'(t) = f(x(t)) >\frac{f(l)}2$$
so $x(t)\ge f(l)t/2 + C$ for some $C\in\mathbb R$, and $x(t)\to\infty$, contrary to (*).

Comment: @Phibetakappa $f$ has a sign, its like $\sin$, it cannot change sign between consecutive roots i.e. between consecutive integers. Thus $x'$ has a sign.

Comment: $f$ has a sign on the image of $x.$

Comment: @Phibetakappa yes, thats correct. there's an interval (n,n+1) that I didn't want to bother  specifying

Comment: How do you know that $l$ is in the image of $x$ so that $f(l) > 0.$ $x$ may not attain it's supremum. Right?

Comment: Otherwise how can you say that $f(l) > 0.$ What you assume is that $f > 0$ on the image of $x.$ How do you ascertain the behaviour of $f$ outside the image of $x$?

Comment: I already read that. I want to say that it may so happen $f(l) < 0.$ Unless $l$ is on the image of $x$ how do I say that $f(l) > 0$?

Comment: @Phibetakappa if there is a point in this open interval ( n,n+1) such that f < 0, then since we already know there is one point where f>0, by continuity of f, there is a zero in this interval, contradicting the above mentioned iff property for f

Comment: What is $(n,n+1)$? I can't see any such thing in your answer.

Comment: Ok. Let me think on my own. Commenting Recommenting irritates me a lot. Thank you so much. No more suggestion is needed.

Comment: @Phibetakappa using the $a$ from your question, $n=\lfloor a \rfloor$. i.e. $(n,n+1)=(\lfloor a \rfloor, \lfloor a \rfloor+1)$. So its not only true that $f>0$ on the image of $x$, but also on the entire open interval $ (\lfloor a \rfloor,\lfloor a \rfloor+1)$. I'll put this in the answer (only just saw "no more suggestion is needed", sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the sign of $x^\prime(t)$ is constant. Suppose that it is positive, the case negative can be dealt with in a similar manner.

As $x^\prime(t)>0$, $x(t)$ is increasing. As you noticed, $x(t)$ is also bounded. So $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} x(t)$ exists and $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} x^\prime(t) =\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f(x(t))=l$ would also exist.

$l=0$ as if not suppose for example $l>0$, we would have $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} x(t) = \pm \infty$ as according to Mean Value Theorem for $x$ large enough $f(x) \ge \frac{l}{2} x$.

Based on the fact that $f$ only vanishes on $\mathbb Z$, you can conclude that $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} x(t)$ is an integer.

Comment: You use continuity of $f.$ Right? If $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} x(t) = L$ then $$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} x'(t) = \lim\limits_{t \to \infty} f(x(t)) = f(L) = l.$$ If we can prove that $l = 0$ then by the definition of $f$ we are through.

Comment: BTW why does $l$ have to  be $0$? I can't get your point.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Because otherwise the limit of $x$ would be $\pm \infty$ as I wrote.

Comment: Why is it the case? Can you please explain it?

Comment: See updated answer.